# how to solve TAR: CANNOT MKDIR PERMISSION DENIED

Tags: permissions, tar, mkdir

## File permissions

I have a file `data.tgz` which I want to uncompress.

> -rw-r--r-- 1 **username** **group** 20342951248 mai   18 11:50 **data.tgz**

---

## Directory permissions

Directory where file is located

> drwxrwxr-x 3 username group 4096 juin   1 17:16 directory/

---

## Uncompress

When I try to uncompress the file by using the following command:

```
tar - xzf data.tgz
```

I get the following error:

```
tar: data : CANNOT MKDIR PERMISSION DENIED
tar: data/a-m-00004.nt.gz : open impossible: No such file or directory
```

When I use `tar -xzvf data.tgz` I get the following errors

---

## Errors

```
tar: data : mkdir impossible: Permission non accordée
tar: data/a-m-00013.nt.gz : open impossible: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
data/a-m-00012.nt.gz
tar: data : mkdir impossible: Permission non accordée
tar: data/a-m-00012.nt.gz : open impossible: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
data/a-m-00015.nt.gz
tar: data : mkdir impossible: Permission non accordée
tar: data/a-m-00015.nt.gz : open impossible: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
data/a-m-00014.nt.gz
tar: data : mkdir impossible: Permission non accordée
tar: data/a-m-00014.nt.gz : open impossible: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
data/a-m-00017.nt.gz
tar: data : mkdir impossible: Permission non accordée
tar: data/a-m-00017.nt.gz : open impossible: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
data/a-m-00016.nt.gz
tar: data : mkdir impossible: Permission non accordée
tar: data/a-m-00016.nt.gz : open impossible: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
data/a-m-00019.nt.gz
```

---

## Google translation

```
tar: data: mkdir impossible not granted Permissions
    tar: data / am-00013.nt.gz: Can not open: No such file or folder of this type
    data / a-m-00012.nt.gz
    tar: data: mkdir impossible not granted Permissions
    tar: data / am-00012.nt.gz: Can not open: No such file or folder of this type
    data / a-m-00015.nt.gz
    tar: data: mkdir impossible not granted Permissions
    tar: data / am-00015.nt.gz: Can not open: No such file or folder of this type
    data / a-m-00014.nt.gz
    tar: data: mkdir impossible not granted Permissions
    tar: data / am-00014.nt.gz: Can not open: No such file or folder of this type
    data / a-m-00017.nt.gz
    tar: data: mkdir impossible not granted Permissions
    tar: data / am-00017.nt.gz: Can not open: No such file or folder of this type
    data / a-m-00016.nt.gz
    tar: data: mkdir impossible not granted Permissions
    tar: data / am-00016.nt.gz: Can not open: No such file or folder of this type
    data / a-m-00019.nt.gz
```

Comment: What happens if you add the -verbose flag and the -perserve permissions flag in your command? `tar - xzfvp data.tgz`

Comment: Can I use it not as root? i don't know

Comment: Yes try it as root..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are trying to uncompress in a path you don't have write access to. Try running this command to extract in your user's home directory: `tar -xzf data.tgz /home/yourusername`

Or try with sudo i.e. `sudo tar -xzf data.tgz`

Comment: tar -xzvf data.tgz /home/haniGOTC ==> nothing It's not producing any result on the screen

Comment: What OS are you running? Are you able to sudo?

Comment: No i can't sudo actually. because I am running on a server and using Linux kubuntu. I didn't mention it but the file is located on a remote server.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the file from the server to your machine? Do you have the credentials to do so? If so, run `sftp user@host:/path/to/data.tgz ~/some/local/directory` or `scp user@host:/path/to/data.tgz ~/some/local/directory` and then navigate to that directory and attempt to extract. You could also try removing the hyphens I've heard that GNU has some interesting behavior with tar optional arguments

Comment: ah yes that's what i am trying to do now. I think it is working. But I really wanted to know why it is giving me these errors.

Comment: I uncompressed the file in my home directory on the remote server it worked. What do you think is the issue with the other directory?

Comment: Most paths external to your home directory need root privileges in order to create folders, which is probably the issue you're running into